# Errors Concerning \spacefactor and \mathaccents

Tags: errors, natbib

I am currently writing a document in LaTeX in which I was hoping to use some variables that have diacritic markings.  When I was initially composing the source code, I simply downloaded the package "natbib" and there were no issues compiling the umlauts and macrons (using the syntax {"a} and {=a} respectively) that I wanted to add to variables.  However, as I reopened the document and attempted to compile, I have received the following errors at several locations: "Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode" and "You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode."

Here is the opening of my code, with the packages that I have downloaded, in addition to one section of the code in which I was receiving this error frequently (I imagine that issues elsewhere in the file are analogous).

In addition, please tailor your advice to someone whose knowledge of compilers is very limited.  I'm only an actuarial student, not a software engineer!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,
  amsfonts, graphicx}

\usepackage{actuarialangle}
\usepackage{natbib}


\\ACCUMULATED VALUE:  $AV={\"s}_{\actuarialangle{n}i}=\dfrac{(1+i)^n-1}{d}$
\\PERPETUITY-IMMEDIATE: begins one period before first payment, continues indefinitely.  PRESENT VALUE: $a_{\actuarialangle{\infty}i}=\dfrac{1}{i}$.
\\PERPETUITY-DUE: begins exactly at period before first payment, continues indefinitely.${\"a__{\actuarialangle{\infty}i}}=\dfrac{1}{d}$.
\\CONTINUOUS ANNUITY: \\PRESENT VALUE: ${\={a}_{\actuarialangle{n}{i}}}=\dfrac{1-v^n}{\delta}=\dfrac{i}{\delta}a_{\actuarialangle{n}i}$.
\\ACCUMULATED VALUE: ${\={s}_{\actuarialangle{n}i}}=\dfrac{(1+i)^n-1}{\delta}=\dfrac{i}{\delta}s_{\actuarialangle{n}i}$.

\\CONNECTING IDENTITIES:
${\"a_{{\actuarialangle{n}i}}}=(1+i)a_{\actuarialangle{n}i}=1+{a_{\actuarialangle{n-1}i}=\dfrac{i}{d}{a_{{\actuarialangle{n}i}}}$
\\${\"s_{{\actuarialangle{n}i}}}=(1+i)s_{\actuarialangle{n}i}={s_{\actuarialangle{n+1}i}}-1=\dfrac{i}{d} * {s_{\actuarialangle{n}i}}

\vspace{.15in}
\centerline {\textsf{\textbf{Methods of Interest Rate Collection}}}}
\vspace{.15in}
PORTFOLIO RATE METHOD: All funds in the account at a given time earn the same interest.
\\YIELD CURVE METHOD: Different proportions of the account earn different amounts of interest depending on the time of deposit into the account
\vspace{.15in}
\centerline {\textsf{\textbf{Geometric Annuities}}}}
\\TWO METHODS OF CALCULATING PRESENT VALUE (one period before first payment, assuymin k adf i accumulation begin at the second payment):
\\$PV=\dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac{1+k}{1+i}\right)^n}{i-k}$.
\\$PV=\dfrac{1}{1+i}{\"a_{{\actuarialangle{n}i'}}}$, where $i'=\dfrac{i-k}{1+k}$.
```

Comment: If you want two dots over `s`, type `\ddot{a}`; similarly, for a bar, `\bar{s}`.

Comment: you also get errors from the mis-used `\\  ` commands, unrelated to accents.